# Update all objects property value in array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have array of objects, that I get by array.filter. Now I want to make .map() function on this array and change specific object property in all objects in this array. Something like this

```
.map(task => task.description = task.description.replace(...);
```

But this gives me array of strings, not array of objects with this updated property. How to make this returning whole objects with just description updated?

Comment: Can you add example data array and the result you want?

Comment: The return value of an assignment is the assigned value. So your are mapping every task to the value returned by `task.description.replace(...)`. Since you don't actually want to compute new values, maybe use `.forEach` instead of `.map`.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to use "=" after arrow function if you do not explicite the return value

Try this :

```js
const test = tasks.map(task => {
  task.description = task.description.replace(...)
  return task
});
console.log(test)
```

Answer (score -1):

remember that, once you've `.filter` followed by `.map`, better to use `.reduce()` otherwise you'll loop twice on the same array.